# Join two unsigned chars + mallock u_chars

Tags: c++, unsigned-char

How does one properly allocate array of unsigned chars?

```
packet = (u_char*) malloc (20*sizeof(u_char)); //is it simmilar to u_char packet[20]?
```

---

I have 2 functions which are declared as follows

```
u_char *frame(bool type, char* srcmac, char* dstmac);
u_char *ip(bool type, char* srcip, char* dstip);
```

how can I concatenate those 2 unsigned chars? I tried memcpy, strcat[only for char].

```
u_char *concat(u_char *s1, u_char *s2) {

    u_char *result = (u_char*) malloc((sizeof(s1)+sizeof(s2)+1));//+1 for the zero-terminator

    memcpy(result, s1, sizeof(s1));
    memcpy(result, s2, sizeof(s2)); //I am overwriting result already and sizeof is size of pointer...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I retagged. Is it done-able in both?

Comment: Check the value of sizeof(s1) in the function...

Comment: `printf("sizeof(s1) = %i", sizeof(s1));` outputs: **sizeof(s1) = 4**, (I know its C syntax, I have snippets for that)

Comment: @Kyslik: They are different languages. You are using C idioms right now. You shouldn't, if you're writing C++. The advice will differ completely depending on the language.

Comment: Are ù_char`s by any chance `unsigned char`, and thus per definition size 1 char? No need for sizeof(u_char) then...

Comment: Yes, I figured that myself that `malloc (20*sizeof(u_char))` is "same" as `malloc (20)`, thank you for input.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have made snippets for C therefore I use C idioms for this kind of "debuging" (accesing quick variable data).

Comment: @Kyslik: I have occasionally written in other languages too but I don't see that as any reason to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
u_char *concat(u_char *s1, u_char *s2) {
u_char *result = (u_char*) malloc((sizeof(s1)+sizeof(s2)+1));
```

This doesn't make any sense. Why do you care how big the pointers are? And how is this function supposed to concatenate two things without knowing how big they are? Also:

```
memcpy(result, s1, sizeof(s1));
memcpy(result, s2, sizeof(s2));
```

Should be:

```
memcpy(result, s1, s1_size);
memcpy(result + s1_size, s2, s2_size);
```

You have to track the sizes of the `s1` and `s2` objects yourself. I called those variables `s1_size` and `s2_size`, but they can be constants. Don't use `sizeof` on a pointer or you get the size of the pointer. The `sizeof` function tells you the size of a type, known at compile time.

Since this is C++, why not just use `std::vector<unsigned char>` and then `+` and `+=` will work nicely. Otherwise, consider a `struct` that encapsulates both a pointer and a size_t.

Comment: "You have to track the sizes of the s1 and s2 objects yourself." That is thing I was worried about. Thanks a lot. :)